# Sorting Choices in Choice Field

Tags: choice-field, sorting, list-column, choices

I have created a list of choices in the choice field. How do I sort them alphabetically?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to sort the choices? In List view or in drop-down on list forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to sort the choices list in choice column drop-down on list/library forms(Correct me if I am wrong).

For a column configured as a Choice column, the order in which the items in the Choice list are presented is the order in which they are entered and listed in the **Type each choice on a separate line** text box in the **Additional Column Settings** group of the column's settings.

For example,  if you have entries listed like so in this text-box:

- Choice A
- Choice B
- Choice C

then that's how they will be shown in the Choice column menu.

**Work Around**:

Follow below steps:

1. Copy all the choices from the column settings of choice field.
2. Create blank Excel file and paste these choices in file.
3. Sort the column in Excel alphabetically.
4. Copy the sorted values from excel file.
5. Paste the choices in choice list in columns settings of choice field.
6. Save the column settings.

**References**:

1. [How to alphabetize in Excel: sort columns and rows A-Z or Z-A](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/04/11/alphabetize-excel-sort-columns-rows/).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. All sorted ;)