# SharePoint REST API Get Choice Dropdown Index

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, choice-field

I have a dropdown with 5 string values.

I can use following request to get string values of the dropdown for every list item:

```
https://someurl/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items(1845)?$select=Consequence
```

Result is returned with this property:

```
<d:Consequence>Moderate</d:Consequence>
```

"Moderate" is at index 4 in the dropdown list, can I get that index instead of text value?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, it should not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is **No**.

There is no index associated with the choice/option inside the choice column.

> For a column configured as a Choice column, the order in which the items in the Choice list are presented is the order in which they are entered and listed in the **Type each choice on a separate line** text box in the **Additional Column Settings** group of the column's settings.

**Reference**: [Sorting Choices in Choice Field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266023/sorting-choices-in-choice-field)

Also, when you inspect the choice column on SharePoint list form, you can see the same choice in `value` attribute as well as display text of `option` element.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ali, Does this answer your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same problem in future. If you have any doubt please ask here.